# Generate record for groups that haven't any corresponding values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Please consider this script:

```
declare @Table_City     table(CityName   varchar(50));
declare @Table_Product      table(ProductName   varchar(50));
declare @Table_Data     table(CityName   varchar(50), ProductName  varchar(50), [Count]    int, Price    int)

insert into @Table_City values('Paris'),('London'),('Tokyo'),('Roma'),('Bern'),('Aten')
insert into @Table_Product values('Toys'),('Shoe'),('TV'),('Radio')
insert into @Table_Data values
    ('Paris', 'Shoe', 12, 10000),
    ('Paris', 'TV', 6, 1040),
    ('Bern', 'Radio', 1, 10),
    ('London', 'TV', 32, 21132),
    ('Roma', 'Shoe', 120, 654400),
    ('Aten', 'TV', 20, 35000),
    ('Paris', 'Radio', 17, 2000),
    ('Paris', 'Radio', 2, 300),
    ('Tokyo', 'TV', 100, 1002000),
    ('Aten', 'TV',20 ,4000 ),
    ('Bern', 'TV', 35, 5000),
    ('London', 'Radio', 70, 7000),
    ('London', 'TV',10 ,10000 ),
    ('Aten', 'Shoe',200 ,10500 ),
    ('London', 'Toys', 10, 8000),
    ('Paris', 'Toys',80 , 9000),
    ('Paris', 'Radio',50 ,75000 ),
    ('Tokyo', 'Shoe',45 ,5500 ),
    ('Roma', 'Toys',12 ,6000 ),
    ('Bern', 'Toys',50 ,4800 ),
    ('London', 'TV',40 ,8700 ),
    ('Aten', 'Toys', 80 ,2500 ),
    ('Aten', 'TV', 100 ,12500 )

select CityName, ProductName , sum([count]) , sum(price)
from @Table_Data
group by CityName, ProductName
order by 1, 2
```

this script generate this result:

[image]

but I want this result:

[image]

What is the best way to generate 0 records for those that haven't corresponding values in groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `CROSS JOIN` `@Table_City` with `@Table_Product` then you `LEFT JOIN` to `@Table_Data`

```
SELECT c.CityName, p.ProductName, 
       SUM(COALESCE([Count], 0)) as [Count],
       SUM(COALESCE([Price], 0)) as [Price]
FROM   @Table_City c
       CROSS JOIN @Table_Product p
       LEFT  JOIN @Table_Data d     ON c.CityName    = d.CityName
                                   AND p.ProductName = d.ProductName
GROUP BY c.CityName, p.ProductName
```

Comment: Sorry the result isn't what I want and it is wrong. Count and Price columns have same value for a city

Answer (score 2):

use `isnull()`, `cross apply`, then before joining our `tabledata`

```
SELECT t1.CityName, t2.ProductName, 
       SUM(isnull(d.[Count], 0)) as [Count],
       SUM(isnull(d.[Price], 0)) as [Price]
FROM   @Table_City t1
       CROSS JOIN @Table_Product t2
       LEFT JOIN @Table_Data d ON t1.CityName = d.CityName
             AND d.ProductName = t2.ProductName
GROUP BY t1.CityName, t2.ProductName
ORDER BY t1.CityName, t2.ProductName
```